# Angular 2 Open new window with Angular Component

Tags: angular

Is it possible to open a new window with an angular component, such as for example FAQS. I know this may be treated as re-bootstrapping the current application or an entire new application in general. Just wondering if this is possible? I've tried target="_blank" and that works, locally -- however it re-bootstraps the application.

Comment: Not without loading and starting the app again

Comment: I guess that is fine, however -- if you host the application online, the new page shows up as /404

Comment: do you want to open a new tab or window? a simple href will do

Comment: New tab or window, doesn't matter -- however, the uri is an angular component route, '/testRoute'

Comment: What do you mean *"host the application online"* - where else?

Comment: I mean when you deploy, the route is not recognized because the application is a new application, thus the routing conflicts with the application load

Comment: for example, when you click the link it will open a new page with /route instead of just /, thus /route will be undefined and give a 404

Comment: Sorry I figured out a work around, I believe re-bootstraping the application is not avoidable, so what I had done is added an href that returns the root context of the application; / plus a param indicator such as thisRoute=true;

/?thisRoute=true

on Bootstrap of the application, I check to see whether this route param is there, if it is, navigate according to the condition to the desired route.

Comment: If you've answered your own question, write it up *as an answer*.

Comment: This workaround is not a good one. Your application, whether it opens new windows or not, should allow the user to press F5 and refresh the current page. Or should support to bookmark a URL of your app. Or to send it by email. Read https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml